# Delivery Failed Event in Azure Grid for Blob handling

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I'm changing my azure function trigger from Blob to EventTrigger because, apparently, it should handle the execution with less delay.

I created everything quite easily but to my surprise although the events are fired I get a Delivery Failed Event - NotFound and my function is never fired.

I get no other log, dead-lettering is not saving anything on the container I set... All quite weird.

What be the cause of this? My function runs on a different resource-group but I would assume that could not cause this issue.

Comment: Can you update some property, for instance, *MaxEventDeliveryAttempts* or *labels* in your blob event subscription via a portal? Note, that this update requires a valid response of the destination resource (endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Failed Event - NotFound errors are observed and expected when the event grid tries to deliver the event to the configured endpoint. In this case, looks like the old function app trigger might not be found/deleted. I will suggest you to create a new eventgrid subscription and configured the new function (event grid trigger) and see if you observed the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when changing my azure function from a Blob to EventTrigger with my storage account in a different resource group than my function app.
For me, it ended up being a CORS issue. I added this section to my function app's ARM template and I started to get events

```
"cors": {
  "allowedOrigins": [
    "https://portal.azure.com" 
  ]
}
```