# Delivery events failed in eventgrid

Tags: azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-queues

Created event grid for storage account.
Topic :event grid
Endpoint type:storage queue

When I am trying to deliver
**deliver failure 400 error**
I am new to event grid how to resolve this and how to deliver.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @[Mike Rogers](https://medium.com/@mikerogers1357/azure-event-grid-handling-failures-c4fba42c1bf) Azure Event Grid — Handling Failures document.

> Event Grid allows you to configure the retry policy upon delivery
> failure. By default, when Event Grid receives certain responses when
> sending to a subscriber (like 400 or 413)

To resolve delivery error while creating event subscription you need to enable Retry policy & dead-lettering.

- To create event subscription to storage account,
  Go to>> Created storage account>>events>>+ Event subscription
- Then as shown in below image in **basics tab Topic type** should be **Storage account** and **Endpoint Type** is **Storage Queue** and Then click on Endpoint select the required storage account and queue and click on select.

[image]

- By default, Dead lettering and retry policy is in disabled state you need to enable these to avoid delivery failure errors.

**[Dead letter:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventGrid#set-dead-letter-location)**

> Event Grid dead-lettering enables you to deliver events that can't be
> delivered to subscribers to a dead-letter destination.

- Click on Enable dead lettering and select your storage subscription and blob container as shown.

**[Retry policy:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventGrid#set-retry-policy)**

- Then enable Configuring Retry policy and select Max delivery attempts in between 1 to 30.
  [image]
- Here i have taken 10 as Max delivery attempts and click on create. i have successfully created storage event subscription as shown in below image.
  [image]
  You can also refer these MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-policy) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997604/delivery-failed-event-in-azure-grid-for-blob-handling) questions.